# MySQL Java driver: Rows are not inserted, but no errors appear

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert values into a MySQL database. I get no errors (and `statement.executeUpdate(...)` returns 1), but the rows are not inserted.

I'm using following MySQL driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

I initialize the connection like this:

```
public class MySqlPersistence implements IPersistence {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySqlPersistence.class);
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;

    @Override
    public void init(final String aUserName, final String aPassword, final String aHost,
                     final String aDatabase, final int aPort) {
        final String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + aHost + ":" + aPort + "/" + aDatabase;

        final String schema = readSchemaCreationScript();


        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, aUserName, aPassword);
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            new ScriptRunner(connection).runScript(new StringReader(schema));
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Row insertion happens like this:

```
@Override
public Long createRepositoryIfNotExists(final String aRepoPath) throws SQLException {
    final String cleanPath = aRepoPath.replace('\\', '/');

    final String sql2 = "INSERT INTO repositories (path) VALUES('" + cleanPath + "')";

    int result = statement.executeUpdate(sql2);

    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM repositories WHERE path='" +
            cleanPath + "'");

    Long repoId = null;

    if (resultSet.next())
    {
        repoId = resultSet.getLong("id");
    }

    resultSet.close();

    return repoId;
}
```

When I execute `sql2` in phpMyAdmin, the row is inserted and I don't get any errors.

The MySQL server version is 5.5.40.

What may cause this problem (no rows are inserted and no errors are reported) ?

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` rather than plain `Statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by calling commit before closing the connection.

```
@Override
public void shutdown()
{
    if (statement != null)
    {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        }
    }

    if (connection != null)
    {
        try {
            connection.commit(); // This statement fixed the problem
            connection.close();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I still don't understand, why it helped as I enable auto-commit when opening the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that an Exception or Error is being thrown, and it's being captured without leaving traces. You should create traces before and after the insertion, to see if the line with the insert is really executing without errors.